# Jest - Mock file generated at build time

Tags: jestjs

I have an build file generated when the application is built/served, this build file doesn't exist when jest is run, although it works perfectly when serving the application. So I always receive the following error on jest:

> Cannot find module 'dist/versioninfo' from
> '../src/app.controller.ts'

Reproducible repository:
https://github.com/pedropapa/jest-issue

Just create an file "dist" and run "jest test". The file will exist in "dist" folder, but jest will throw an exception. I already tried the following solution, but it didn't work:

```
jest.mock(
  'dist/versioninfo',
  () => `
export const VERSAO = "0.0.1 (dev)";
export const DESCRICAO = "";
`,
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, digging around jest config I found the solution.

I just needed to change jest.rootDir to "." and include "jest.moduleNameMapper" to my package.json:

Before:

```
"jest": {
 "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
}
```

After:

```
"jest": {
"moduleFileExtensions": [
  "js",
  "json",
  "ts"
],
"rootDir": ".",
"testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
},
"collectCoverageFrom": [
  "**/*.(t|j)s"
],
"coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
"testEnvironment": "node",
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "^dist/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/dist/$1"
}
}
```